# How can I search the info column in Wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-analyzer, packet-capture

Wireshark | Windows

I want to search a packet capture of SMTP traffic for specific addresses/messages. Normally, I just sort the info column and browse but it would be nice if I could just run a search or filter for the specific string I'm looking for.

Is there a way to do this in Wireshark?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to search yur SMTP logs?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open *Edit→Find Packet*. Under *Find* select *String* and under *Search In* select *Packet list*.

---

Update: Wireshark 4.2.0 and later added `_ws.col.*` display filter fields. `_ws.col.info` lets you filter on the "Info" column. For example, `_ws.col.info matches "(?i)donuts"` will case-insensitively match "donuts".

Comment: a bit odd that the search bar is sort of this hidden option. so we just have to know that there's a filter bar and the hidden search bar

Comment: anyone knows of a way to actually filter out instead of "searching" which is helpful yes helps you to find entries in all the clutter, but a filter really should be possible.

Comment: @RicardoMendes 4.2.0 will add a `_ws.col.info` display filter field. It's scheduled for release in mid November 2023, but in the mean time you can use one of the 4.2.0 release candidates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Microsoft Network Monitor to do the trick.
Open your file in Microsoft Network Monitor.
Right-click on an item in the Description column en choose "Add 'Description' to Display Filter" from the context menu.
The Display Filter is added to the Filter Window.
Hit the Apply button on the filter toolbar.

Examples:

```
Description == "HTTP:Request, GET / "
Description.contains("Request")
```

[Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4: Search the Description Column | LoveMyTool](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2011/03/microsoft-network-monitor-34-search-the-description-column-by-joke-snelders.html)